# identify this tree

Tags: species-identification, botany, trees

location: trabzon(turkey) planted for recreational purpose

[image]

[image]

Comment: dont forget to accept good answer

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It is *Rhus typhina*, also known as [staghorn sumac](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rhus_typhina). The plant is originally from north-east America, but is often seen all over the world in Parks or gardens.

[image: Picture taken from naturephoto-cz]

Comment: It's basically a weed here in Canada.